# QRegexp matching

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

**What I am looking to do:**

1. Find all files that are of the type autogen_X.c, autogen_X.h or Project name.c (in the src folder on the root level)
2. Print them out

The QRegExp I have is: \nsrc[^\n]*

**The text that I have is:**

```
####################################################################    
# Files                                                            #
####################################################################

C_SRC +=  \
src/autogen_init.c \
src/autogen_init.h \
src/Project name.c \
lib/src/acmp.c \
lib/src/adc.c \
lib/src/aes.c \`


s_SRC +=  \
Device/Source/G++/startup_32.s


S_SRC +=
```

**The code I have**

```
  QRegExp linkRx = QRegExp("src/[^\\n]*");
  linkRx.indexIn(content);

  foreach (QString match, linkRx.capturedTexts())
  {
    qDebug() << match;
  }
```

**The output I am getting**

```
"src/autogen_init.c \"
```

Should this not match all files that start with just `src/`?

Answer (score 0):

You should preprocess the file, it will simplify the task a lot:

```
text.replace("\\\n", " ");
```

(`\` at the end of a line means *concatenate with the next line*).

Then, you can capture what you want with the regexp `(src/[^ ]*)`. Note the parenthesis, in order to capture text.

Also, this regexp will capture `src/adc.c` in `lib/src/adc.c`. To fix that, you can use a regexp which excludes certain characters from being before "src", example: `([^a-zA-Z_0-9/]src/[^ ]*)`.

Note that it cannot match filenames with spaces in it. By the way, in a normal qmake file, names with spaces are put between quotation marks. You cannot parse correctly quotations marks only with regexps.